# Correlated Subquery SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I am (unsuccessfully) using a correlated subquery on an Invoices  table:

```
Invoices(InvoiceID,  VendorID, InvoiceTotal, PaymentTotal, CreditTotal,.... ),
```

to find the sum of largest unpaid invoices by all vendors, where the unpaid condition is given by `InvoiceTotal-PaymentTotal-CreditTotal <0`:

```
 Select Sum(LargestUnpaid) from 
 (Select   Max(InvoiceTotal) AS LargestUnpaid from Invoices 
  where InvoiceTotal-(PaymentTotal+CreditTotal)<0 group by vendorID ) ;
```

The inner query runs , which is good and bad, since the query is supposed
   to be correlated , but the query as a whole does not run, and I get the  error message:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just FYI, you are not using a correlated subquery there. That is called a derived table. A subquery is called correlated if it references any of the table aliases found in the [outer query's] FROM clause and is located in any of these parts of the [outer] query: the SELECT clause, an APPLY operator, the WHERE clause, the ON subclause of a join.

Comment: @AndriyM: You are correct, Sir, thank you. Additionally, the query in parenthesis runs on its own)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add an alias for the derived table before the `;` for example *VendLargestUnpaidInv*:

```
Select Sum(LargestUnpaid) from
 (Select   Max(InvoiceTotal) AS LargestUnpaid from Invoices 
  where InvoiceTotal-(PaymentTotal+CreditTotal)<0 group by vendorID ) VendLargestUnpaidInv;
```

Comment: Just curious: why does an alias make such a difference?

Answer (score 3):

Or to make it more readable, using CTE (Common Table Expression)

```
With VendLargestUnpaidInv as 
( 
    Select   Max(InvoiceTotal) AS LargestUnpaid from Invoices 
    where InvoiceTotal - (PaymentTotal+CreditTotal)<0 
    group by vendorID
)
select sum(LargestUnpaid) 
from VendLargestUnpaidInv;
```

Comment: Good point, will try this.